# How can value in Javascript be accessed from C# code?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to iterate through `Model.DataList`, however, I'm not able to get Javascript value 'i' in c#. Is it possible to access I from c#?

```
for (var i = 0; i < (@Model.DataList.Count); i++) {  
   var la = (@Model.DataList[i].Latitude)/1000000;
   var lo = (@Model.DataList[i].Longitude)/1000000;
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: la, lng: lo},
      map: map,
      title: "Some title",
      zIndex: i
   });
}
```

Comment: you can do like ViewBag.Count = Model.DataList.Count in C# and then  in your.cshrml use @ViewBag.Count

Comment: @Fran, I think dupe vote is incorrect as OP is trying to access razor value, not trying to pass

Comment: @Satpal I retracted my duplicate vote when I saw your answer and voted it up too :) But because others voted too the comment is still visible. I'm sure there is a duplicate for it as using `Html.Raw(Json(....))` is a common solution to this question. I will delete the dup comment as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the above code is in View, You can use [`Json.Encode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) Method converts a data object to a string that is in the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.

```
var jsObject = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.DataList))
```

Then you can iterate it

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsObject.length; i++) {
    var la = (jsObject[i].Latitude) / 1000000;
    var lo = (jsObject[i].Longitude) / 1000000;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {
                lat: la,
                lng: lo
            },
            map: map,
            title: "Some title",
            zIndex: i
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below approach may it will work for you

-script

```
var list=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SomeEnumerable));

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {  
   var la = list[i].Latitude/1000000;
  var lo = list[i].Longitude/1000000;
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: {lat: la, lng: lo},
   map: map,
  title: "Some title",
  zIndex: i
 });}
```